# Change the style section and subsection of Table of Contents (toc)

Tags: table-of-contents, bold, abnt

I want to take the bold section and subsection of the TOC. 
I use  the class custom abtntex.
I use \tableofcontents*
My summary:

[image]

As I want:

[image]

https://www.overleaf.com/17776192vgbyvhnzxvkn (example code)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) There are thousands of ways to make sections bold in the table of contents, so we can't know how to remove it without seeing the code that produces it. Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your document.

Comment: The first image looks much better and is much easier to read. Why do you want it all squished like that?

Comment: I just want to take the bold section and subsection

Comment: [link](https://www.overleaf.com/17776192vgbyvhnzxvkn) example of code

Comment: @cfr, he wants it all squished because it looks like word.

Comment: @Joseph Why doesn't the OP use Word then? What's the point of using LaTeX in that case? Exception: institutional requirements demand terribly typography, as many North American schools do. Or some journals demand it 'look like Word', but don't care that it isn't Word. (For the latter, use the `philosophy` package.)

Comment: Please post code for a small example here. Please don't rely on external links. Remember that your question is for others as well as you, but the content of external links is very likely to change. So your question should be self-contained insofar as that is at all possible.

Comment: I think the OP just wanted chapters bold in the TOC, but he just specified it in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put in overleaf check it:

or use the below coding in your file:

```
\makeatletter

\def\@secdottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \renewcommand\@dotsep{1}
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \normalfont\leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont#5}%
     \par}%
  \fi}



\renewcommand*\l@section{\@secdottedtocline{2}{60pt}{22pt}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@secdottedtocline{2}{60pt}{22pt}}
\makeatother
```